# no overload for method 'usemysql' takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, .net-5, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString: @"server=localhost;userid=root;password=***;database=coursesystemdb");
    }
```

This is the dbcontext class that ı had used optionsbuilder.usemysql and after upgrade my core to 5.0 and ı take error no overload for method usemsql takes 1 arguments. How can ı solve this?

here is also startup.class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {services.AddCors(options =>
        {options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

        });
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: The error is pretty clear. That method doesn't work with just one parameter. What is the actual signature? Which provider are you using? Oracle's Connector/NET added EF Core support very late and has several problems so people typically use different providers, like Pomelo and MySqlConnector

Comment: BTW it's a very bad idea to specify the database and hard-code the string inside the DbContext. What if you need to target a different database? It's better to use `AddDbContext` to register the DbContext class and specify the database and connection string. This way you can switch databases eg during testing without having to recompile

Comment: Firstly thanks your answer. I understood but it had worked before.when upgrade Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql; extension ı start to take this error. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Did you check the method's documentation? Hovered over `UseMySql` to see what parameters it uses in the tooltip? Obviously the method changed, and the change will be documented

Comment: after this error ı try to do like yours. Im planning to take connections string from appsetting.json and and `AddDbContext`

Comment: additionally ı didnt check firstly googled and look solutions. Im also checking documentation.

Comment: Check the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/Overload_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_MySQLDbContextOptionsExtensions_UseMySQL.htm)  There isn't an overload of `UseMySQL` that takes a single argument.

Comment: Are you using the same library that was working.  Was old code working with Net 5 or a different version of Net?

Comment: I am using same library. My code was working 3.1 version and upgrade 5 now as ı understand want one more argument. @jdweng

Comment: did source code change or did you just recompile same source with Net 5?  There are a lot of known error when upgrading.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/5.0?force_isolation=true

Comment: See foillowing : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/tutorial-use-entity-framework-core-5-0-in-net-core-3-1-with-mysql-database-by2/?force_isolation=true

Comment: ı didnt change source code just recompile with net 5.

Comment: btw ı dont use code first approach and dont have migration class.

Comment: Pomelo's `UseMySql()` signature differs from Oracle's `UseMySQL()` call, not just in its capitalization, but also in its mandatory parameters. So my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the sample code on our [front page/readme](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql#3-services-configuration):

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Replace with your connection string.
        var connectionString = "server=localhost;user=root;password=1234;database=ef";

        // Replace with your server version and type.
        // Use 'MariaDbServerVersion' for MariaDB.
        // Alternatively, use 'ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)'.
        // For common usages, see pull request #1233.
        var serverVersion = new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 21));

        // Replace 'YourDbContext' with the name of your own DbContext derived class.
        services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(
            dbContextOptions => dbContextOptions
                .UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion)
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging() // <-- These two calls are optional but help
                .EnableDetailedErrors()       // <-- with debugging (remove for production).
        );
    }
}
```

It shows you how to call `UseMySql()` and that it expects 2 parameters: the connection string and the version of the database server that you are using.

You can also let the server version be detected automatically, instead of specifying it explicitly (showed using `OnConfiguring()` here, which you used in your OP):

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    var connectionString = @"server=localhost;userid=root;password=***;database=coursesystemdb";
    var serverVersion = ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString);

    optionsBuilder
        .UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion)
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging() // <-- These two calls are optional but help
        .EnableDetailedErrors();      // <-- with debugging (remove for production).
}
```

We added a mandatory `serverVersion` parameter to the `UseMySql()` method in 5.0, because Pomelo supports MySQL and MariaDB in different versions and needs to know which one you use, so that it can support your database server in the best way possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot your answers. I checked document and edited like this code that didnt back error. If that happened again,ı write again thanks again @lauxjpn